# Emit a boolean from AuthGuard - Angular 4

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, jwt

I use JWT in a server node to check if the user is connected.
AuthGuard in an observable, it will check if my user is connected :

```
  canActivate(): Observable<any> {
    if ( !localStorage.getItem('currentUser')){
      return Observable.of(false);
    }
    // Authorization with JWT Token
    const options = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'BEARER ' + localStorage.getItem('currentUser') )
    };
    //Check if the JWT Token is always available and if the signature is right
    return this.http.get(environment.api + 'checkToken', options )
      .map(() => true).catch(() => {
        return Observable.of(false);
      });
  }
```

Now I would like to emit the boolean from canActivate to an other component. My other component is the nav-bar of my website. I want to hide some link in the navbar when the user is disconnected. However, I would like to displays some elements when the user is connected.

But even when I use an observable in the constructor of my navbar component, it will check just one time if the user is connected.

Do you have any ideas to emit the boolean from my AuthGuard to my navbar component ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use [resolve](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve) on the route and do almost the same things in resolver class. Then you can access boolean value (or user object itself if you resolve it) from the component by injecting [ActivatedRouteSnapshot](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRouteSnapshot#data).
Or if you don't want round trips then you can subscribe to the observable before you return it from `canActivate` and emit the value to some service that contains [Subject](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/subject.md) for example so you would be able to inject this service into your component and use that subject.